# How enable iCloud-based recovery when setting up FileVault via the command-line tool fdesetup?

Tags: terminal, icloud, command-line, filevault

When enabling FileVault using the GUI (System Preferences < Security & Privacy < FileVault), it is possible to configure a linked iCloud account which can be leveraged for lost password recovery:

[image: Screenshot System Preferences FileVault]

I would like to set up FileVault via the command-line, as a part of a Mac provisioning script.  FileVault can be enabled via the command-line tool fdesetup: `sudo fdesetup enable`

I cannot find the option to enable the iCloud link via this comand-line tool fdesetup. Can anybody help me with this?